# Why there is only one input in attention model in Keras?

Tags: keras, attention-model

In this code, the author defined 2 input, but there is only one input feed to the model. There should be some bugs, however, I can run it. I wonder why I can successfully run this code.

```
def han():
    # refer to 4.2 in the paper whil reading the following code

    # Input for one day : max article per day =40, dim_vec=200
    input1 = Input(shape=(40, 200), dtype='float32')

    # Attention Layer
    dense_layer = Dense(200, activation='tanh')(input1)
    softmax_layer = Activation('softmax')(dense_layer)
    attention_mul = multiply([softmax_layer,input1])
    #end attention layer


    vec_sum = Lambda(lambda x: K.sum(x, axis=1))(attention_mul)
    pre_model1 = Model(input1, vec_sum)
    pre_model2 = Model(input1, vec_sum)

    # Input of the HAN shape (None,11,40,200)
    # 11 = Window size = N in the paper 40 = max articles per day, dim_vec = 200
    input2 = Input(shape=(11, 40, 200), dtype='float32')

    # TimeDistributed is used to apply a layer to every temporal slice of an input 
    # So we use it here to apply our attention layer ( pre_model ) to every article in one day
    # to focus on the most critical article
    pre_gru = TimeDistributed(pre_model1)(input2)

# bidirectional gru
    l_gru = Bidirectional(GRU(100, return_sequences=True))(pre_gru)

    # We apply attention layer to every day to focus on the most critical day   
    post_gru = TimeDistributed(pre_model2)(l_gru)

# MLP to perform classification
    dense1 = Dense(100, activation='tanh')(post_gru)
    dense2 = Dense(3, activation='tanh')(dense1)
    final = Activation('softmax')(dense2)
    final_model = Model(input2, final)
    final_model.summary()

    return final_model
```

Answer (score 0):

Keras models can be used as layers. In the code above, `input1` is used to define `pre_model{1,2}`. The models are then called bellow by the model named `final_model`.

`final_model` has a single input layer.

Comment: Thank you! But there is no input for pre_model when I train the final model, I mean, no data feed to the pre_model but I can still train it, why?

Comment: In the line ```pre_gru = TimeDistributed(pre_model1)(input2)``` you have pre_model1 being called with ```input2```. This becomes the ```pre_model1``` input. A model is just a sequence of layers.